# design database model and related sql queries

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design, data-modeling

Develop the rdbms for the administrative structure of an organisation. Each employee belong to a certain dept and is associated with multiple projects. each manager is an employee who manages several projects as well as several employee. Each project executes for a certain duration. employees stay in organisations for a certain duration.

Queries:

1. find no of employees who has worked is every project
2. find max no of employees working at a time in project 'x'
3. find the unproductive managers who manages less than 5 project in last 1 year
4. find the dept whose employees handled maximum project in last 1 year

edit:
I am not able to decide how to deal with the time constraint in the last 3 queries. 
I have made 3 tables:

- EMPLOYEE with attributes: emp_id,name,dept,manager_id where emp_id is primary key and manager_id is self referential foreign key
- PROJECT with p_id,p_name,manager_id where p_id is primary key
- ALLOTMENT with emp_id,p_id where both attributes make a composite primary key

The above helps me answer the first query but how do I add the time constraints to answer the rest of the queries. Do I need date-time attribute or a simple duration attribute will work or something else is required here? please help.

Comment: We're happy to assist students.  If you just post your homework question, though, you're unlikely to get much help.  Ask 1 question, not multiple questions.  Show us what you have tried.  Tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: added an edit @JustinCave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALLOTMENT is the intersection between EMPLOYEE and PROJECT.  It records the employees working on a project.

However, employees join projects *and leave projects*.  Projects grow and shrink in their resourcing.  So clearly ALLOTMENT needs columns to indicate the time span of a particular assignment, say START_DATE and END_DATE.

Once you add those columns you will be able to answer the remaining questions.  Some of them will remain tricky (especially 2) but at least you will have the information required.

Incidentally, you probably ought to have a DEPARTMENT table but you can write those queries without it. Also, in real life a PROJECT would have an initiation date and (we hope) a completion date.  However they too are not required for the queries you have to write.

Answer (score -2):

In the `project` table consider adding two columns `start_date` and `duration`| `End_date` of the project. I think this will be sufficient for you to work through the last 3 queries.

You can consider having another column `No_of_Employees_under_project` in `project` table, which is normalized and will dynamically reflect employees joining or leaving the project. This column should be added only after measuring the `gain` against the `cost of normalization`.

Comment: Um, a  column called `No_of_Employees_under_project` is a *de-normalization* because it is a derived field.  This is the sort of thing which is useful in a data warehouse but considerably less so in an OLTP environment.  In particular we need to watch out that the overhead of maintaining the column (which include serialization in a multi-user environment) doesn't outweigh the purported gain from pre-calculating the value.  If I were a teacher I would mark down any student who proposed such a thing.

Comment: Sure thing, gain should be evaluated against the cost of normalization. I have made the necessary edit. Thanks .

Comment: Also, the phrasing of the second query implies that the number of employees working on a given project can vary over time.  Your proposal doesn't reflect that, and wouldn't allow the OP to satisfy that requirement.

Comment: It's the cost of *de-normalization* .  Normalization is the process of removing redundant data.  You're adding it.